# iPhone + AdMob + remove the Ad view

Tags: iphone, admob, ads-api

I have integrated AdMob in my iPhone application.

I am adding an Ad view in of my UIViewController as follows:

```
ProgrammaticAdViewController *temp = [[ProgrammaticAdViewController alloc] init];
temp = [[ProgrammaticAdViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[self.view addSubview:temp.view];
```

So, I will be able to see an Ad view on top of my UIViewController.

Now I have two problems:

1. I am not able to tap on certain buttons of my UIViewController on which I have added the Ad View. So, for temporary purpose I adding the Ad view as:

   ```
   [self.view insertSubView:temp.view atIndex:1];
   ```
2. I want to remove the Ad view after sometime so I am using:

   ```
   [temp.view removeFromSuperView];
   ```

But my Ad view is not being removed.

Please help me.

Regards,
Pratik

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a memory leak here:

```
ProgrammaticAdViewController *temp = [[ProgrammaticAdViewController alloc] init];
temp = [[ProgrammaticAdViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
```

Pick one, don't use both.

You could then set a 'tag' for "temp":

```
temp.tag = 123;
```

Then when you want to remove it use:

```
[[self.view viewWithTag:123] removeFromSuperview];
```

Hope that helps

Comment: temp.tag will not work because temp is the instance of ViewController class and does not have tag as its property.

Comment: Declare it in the .h file then.

Comment: @Tom: Sorry I am not getting your last comment...plz can you explain in some detail

Comment: Sorry, should have been clearer! Declare "temp" in the .h file of the class you using it in, then you can access it anywhere in the class file.

Comment: @Tom: I think your misunderstanding...its not the case of accessing "temp", I am saying that temp is the object of type ViewController class and objects of ViewController does not have "tag" property. "tag" property is for objects of UIView class.

Comment: Try setting a tag on "temp.view" then.